# .NET AJAX asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've been tasked with including asynchronous calls to my webpage and I'm not sure where to start. Currently, my webpage takes user input from a drop down list, converts it into a list of CodeDesc objects, serializes it all into JSON and then deserializes it back so it can be displayed in a GridView on the screen. (I could just make it spit out the CodeDesc object back to the GridView but this is the way my manager wanted it so..).

In any case, now I need the results to be displayed without reloading the page and after some research I read that AJAX was a good way to do it. Unfortunately, I'm confused how I can connect it all and actually use it. My attempts are below but I could really use some guidance on the matter.

HTML (partial):

```
<script>
$("#Button1").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: ??'GET'??,
            contentType: ??
            success: function (?? Call deserializeJSONResults function ??) {
                $('#GridView2').html("");
                for (var i = 0; i < deserializedProduct.length; i++) {
                    $("#GridView2").append(deserializedProduct.id, deserializedProduct.code, deserializedProduct.);
                }
            }
       });
});</script>
```

Without using AJAX my code is below:

CS:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataConnector dc = new DataConnector();
        GridView2.DataSource = dc.deserializeJSONResults(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

Backend:

```
    //Return results to GridView2 as list of CodeDesc objects
    public List<CodeDesc> getQueryResults(string searchTerm)
    {
        try
        {
            List<CodeDesc> L = new List<CodeDesc>();
            string query = "select id, code, descr from code_desc where code_type_id = (select id from code_desc where descr = :searchTerm)";

            // Create the OracleCommand
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("searchTerm", searchTerm));
                con.Open();

                // Execute command, create OracleDataReader object
                using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        CodeDesc c = new CodeDesc
                        {
                            id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                            code = reader.GetString(1),
                            description = reader.GetString(2)
                        };
                        L.Add(c);
                    }
                }
            }

            return L;

        }
    //catch clause here
    }



    //Convert to JSON and parse
    public List<CodeDesc> deserializeJSONResults(string searchTerm)

    {
        List<CodeDesc> L = getQueryResults(searchTerm);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(L, Formatting.Indented);

        //deserialize object
        List<CodeDesc> deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CodeDesc>>(json);

        return deserializedProduct;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have little development experience and this is my first time with web/.NET development

Comment: You probably don't need to set the `contentType`.  A `dataType` of `'json'` seems like what you want.  You also need a `url` value in the AJAX request of course, and probably some `data` value to send to the server.  It sounds like you're just looking for tutorials on using AJAX with ASP.NET, there should be many on Google.  It looks like you're using WebForms, so you'll probably make use of WebMethods for handling those AJAX requests.  Also note that messing with WebForms controls directly in client-side code might be a bit of a fight to get it to work with WebForms itself.

Comment: why does the "deserializeJSONResults" method serialise some data, and then immediately deserialise it again on the next line, without making any other use of the serialised data? That makes no sense at all, it's a complete waste of time. As the above comment mentioned, to use ajax you need to re-architect your code a little bit - there are plenty of tutorials about using WebMethods available online, which is probably the best solution in a WebForms application.

Comment: @ADyson I'm assuming my manager has plans for the serialized data later on that I haven't been made aware of. Thus it's not in the code yet.

Comment: Generally, the only reason to serialise to JSON is at the point where you send the data back to the web browser, as the response to an AJAX request. You occasionally find people storing data in JSON form in their data store, but usually that's because they received the data in that format and don't want to have to convert it/parse it in order to store it. So you'll need that serialisation code (or something like it) when you create your WebMethod, but I doubt there's much other use for it.

Comment: @ADyson Sending the data back to the web browser as the response to an AJAX request is what I want to do. Do you know how to implement that?

Comment: Yes. Using C# WebMethods as suggested by myself and David above is one way, which would suit you as you're using ASP.NET WebForms. There are dozens of tutorials for it online. I suggest you try it, and if you run into difficulties, ask a more specific question about it that would be better suited to the format of SO. As it is, this question is a bit too broad and some might consider it off-topic.

Comment: @ADyson Apologies. I don't know what a WebForm is I'm just making a regular ASP.NET Web Application.. I'll do more research and ask a more specific question next time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: WebForms is one of the two implementation frameworks available for making an ASP.NET application. The other is MVC. I can see by the style of code you've shown and the components referenced that you're using the WebForms framework. If you were using MVC, the solution for handling ajax requests would be a bit different.